# Appium best strategy to find elements when there's no ID

Tags: python, appium

i've just started using appium with python and don't know how i should find elements when there's no ID. Using XPATH does not work all the time, so i was wondering what is the best way to find some element.

All i have is this information

[image]

I tried to combine the `class name` with `text` as

```
fin = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
                    "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Relatório Financeiro']"
                )
```

But it's not working when i try to click it

Answer (score 1):

This usually works for me in most of the cases.

```
//{packageName}[@content-desc="{text of the element}"]
```